# XCODE 7 App on Device Crashing

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to work on device.But application is working perfect in Simulator.What should I do ? Do you have any suggestion about that ?

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error
```

Thank You

Comment: Also application was working perfectly when I'm working with ios 8 sdk & xcode 6

Comment: I just had the same problem and solved it by setting the new "Enable Bitcode" flag in the Build Settings to "No".

Answer (score 6):

Do a quick Clean / Build and try again.

Comment: I did but it's not worked

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: 
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxx/CSGB.app/CSGB
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/lib/system/introspection/: not a file
 /usr/lib/: not a file
(lldb)

Comment: @Murat Kaya any updates?

Comment: Yes,  It's happining because of beta version.I changed the version of my app to ios 9 and its worked.But first do a clean and build.